# Magneto 2: Need to remove decimal from price on product detail page

Tags: magento2, price, product-detail-page

I want to remove the decimal in price on product details page. Although it removes in listing page, but still showing decimal in discount and final price on product details page.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Create file and use this code :

**=> From :**

> vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/base/templates/product/price/amount/default.phtml

**=> To :**

> app/design/frontend/VendorName/ModuleName/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/price/amount/default.phtml

this file is defined from `\Magento\Framework\Pricing\Render\Amount`

The price itself is coming from this call:

```
<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->formatCurrency($block->getDisplayValue(), (bool)$block->getIncludeContainer()) ?>
```

If we take a look at the file that this method is created based on the class it's inheriting (`/vendor/magento/framework/Pricing/Render/Amount.php`)

Update line no 24

```
<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->formatCurrency($block->getDisplayValue(), (bool)$block->getIncludeContainer()) ?>
```

To

```
<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->formatCurrency($block->getDisplayValue(), (bool)$block->getIncludeContainer() , 0) ?>
```

You need to override

> vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/base/web/js/price-utils.js

To

> app/design/frontend/VendorName/ModuelName/Magento_Catalog/web/js/price-utils.js

and change the value of precision on line 38:

```
var precision = isNaN(format.requiredPrecision = Math.abs(format.requiredPrecision)) ? 2 : format.requiredPrecision,
```

To

```
var precision = 0,
```

Comment: It works only for category view. Any idea how to apply to catalog page too?

Answer (score 0):

The best way I could find is to change the `priceFormat` function from `Magento_Catolag/js/price-utils.js` inside my `priceBox.js`, so in your `requirejs-config.js`

```
var config = {

"map": {

"*": {

"priceBox" : "Vendor_ModuleName/js/price-box"

}
}
};
```

Copy the whole `Magento_Catalog/js/price-box.js` to your `Vendor/ModuleName/view/frontend/web/js/price-box.js` and after the `use strict` add:

```
var globalPriceFormat = {

        requiredPrecision: 2,

        integerRequired: 1,

        decimalSymbol: ',',

        groupSymbol: ',',

        groupLength: ','

    };
```

Under this copy the `formatPrice function` from `price-utils.js`

Change:

```
function formatPrice(amount, format, isShowSign) {

var s = '',

            precision, integerRequired, decimalSymbol, groupSymbol, groupLength, pattern, i, pad, j, re, r, am;
```

To

```
function formatPriceHack(amount, format, isShowSign) {
var s = '',

            precision = 0, integerRequired, decimalSymbol, groupSymbol, groupLength, pattern, i, pad, j, re, r, am;
```

Also comment:

```
//precision = isNaN(format.requiredPrecision = Math.abs(format.requiredPrecision)) ? 2 : format.requiredPrecision;
```

And change:

`i = stringPad('0', pad) + i;`

To inside formatPriceHack:

```
i = utils.strPad('0', pad) + i;
```

And last, change inside the `reloadPrice` function from `priceBox`:

```
price.formatted = utils.formatPrice(price.final, priceFormat);
```

To:

```
price.formatted = formatPriceHack(price.final, priceFormat);
```

That's it.