# How to remove decimal points from price in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, price

In `app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_ConfigurableProduct/templates/product/price/final_price.phtml` of listing page price is appearing like ₹50.00 . I want to show it as ₹50.

I tried using

```
echo $this->helper('Magento\Framework\Pricing\Helper\Data')->currency(number_format(50,2),true,false);
```

and

```
echo $this->helper('Magento\Framework\Pricing\Helper\Data')->currency(number_format(50,0),true,false);
```

but it gives ₹50.00 and not ₹50. How I can achieve that?

Comment: Refer this : https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/258549/51810 & tell me if not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To correct the product page you also should modify next javascript:

```
/vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/base/web/js/price-utils.js
```

on line 38 change

```
var precision = isNaN(format.requiredPrecision = Math.abs(format.requiredPrecision)) ? 2 : format.requiredPrecision,
```

for

```
var precision = 0,
```

Hope this help.

I found this in: [Magento 2 : How to remove decimal points from the price](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/96534/magento-2-how-to-remove-decimal-points-from-the-price)

also another free extension available 
[magento2-price-decimal](https://github.com/lillik/magento2-price-decimal)